# React dnd is not working in latest version of chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, react-hooks, chromium, react-dnd

We have an application, which is using react drag and drop. Basically we have network file which we want to drop to a list.We are using the useDrag method from the library[version react-dnd : 11.1.3 ]. It was working fine in Chrome version older  than 107.0.5304.88.But it is currently failing  with Aw, Snap! Error code: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.
Nothing is captured in the developer’s tool as it is getting disconnected. It is failing in chromium-based browsers only while working fine in Mozilla and Safari.

Code:

```
 const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag({
    item: { type: 'file', file, selectedKeys } as DragItem,
    canDrag: !disabled && selected,
    collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.getItem()?.selectedKeys.includes(file.key),
    }),
  });
```

Chrome Crash report:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffe18fb66aa (chrome!CrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange+0x000000000292314a)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000038
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000038
PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe
READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000038 
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.
EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000038
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_c0000005_chrome.dll!Unknown
```

Tried disabling the drag monitor, but doesn't work as well.
Please suggest what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with chromium version. Hence closing this issue.
Not Reproducible on
110.0.5439.0 - Canary
109.0.5414.10 - Dev
108.0.5359.48 - Beta

Reproducible on
107.0.5304.121 - Stable

Comment: You haven't actually closed the question, and there's no need for an answer on a question that isn't reproducible. I just voted to close it as non-reproducible, and you should have an option to vote in agreement